# How can I establish a default String value on a Tkinter Spinbox?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have read a good solution for establishing a default numerical value on a Tkinter Spinbox widget when you use the from_ to options. But I have not seen a single one that can help establish a value (numerical or string) from a tuple.

My code is as follows, and is intended to set a default value in a Tkinter Spinbox widget from a tuple:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+50+50')
root.title('Prueba')

t = ('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five')
v = t[3]

var = StringVar()
var.set(v)
sb = Spinbox(root, values=t, textvariable=var, width=10)
sb.place(x=5, y=15)

root.mainloop()
```

Another variant that I have tried is the following:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+50+50')
root.title('Prueba')

var = StringVar()
var.set('Four')
sb = Spinbox(root, ('One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'), textvariable=var, width=10)
sb.place(x=5, y=15)

root.mainloop()
```

The only way the set method works on Spinbox (and which I took from here) is the following and only works with numbers and within a range established as options in the Spinbox widget:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+50+50')
root.title('Prueba')

var = StringVar()
var.set(4)
sb = Spinbox(root, from_=1, to=5, textvariable=var, width=10)
sb.place(x=5, y=15)

root.mainloop()
```

Can please anyone help me to find out how to establish a default value in a Tkinter Spinbox from a Tuple? I will appreciate that greatly!

Answer (score 3):

If you move the line `var.set(v)` to be *after* creating the widget, the default value will be set.

```
var = StringVar()
sb = Spinbox(root, values=t, textvariable=var, width=10)
var.set(v)
```

Comment: How can I buy you a beer, Bryan! Thanks so much! ;)

Comment: Hi @EnriqueBoeneker! About a year ago, you got this helpful answer to your question. Please mark the answer as "accepted"!  It removes your question from the "unanswered" list, and gives a little extra rep to the guy that helped you. Have a good day :)

Comment: @bitsmack: Enrique hasn't been back to this site in nearly a year. He likely won't ever see your comment.

Comment: True enough. I was hoping he might get his comments emailed to him. Low chances, but, why not? :) Thanks for this answer, btw, it helped!