# Python Tkinter Spinbox seems to reset the variable value

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working with Python 2.6.5, and TKinter.TkVersion 8.5

Here is a MWE of the buggy behavior :

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

classic_var = tk.IntVar()
classic_var.set(2)
classic_spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=3,textvariable=classic_var)
classic_spinbox.pack()

values_var = tk.IntVar()
values_var.set(2)
values_spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, values=(0, 1, 2, 3), textvariable=values_var)
values_spinbox.pack()

print classic_var.get() #expected : 2, actual : 2
print values_var.get() #expected : 2, actual : 0

root.mainloop()
```

I would expect for value_var to be "2" even after the Spinbox initialization.

Here you can see a screenshot of the result :
[image: A display of a probable tkinter bug]

Is it a known bug ? Is there a workaround other than this ?

```
initial_value = 2
values_var = tk.IntVar()
values_spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, ...
values_var.set(initial_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

From testing it myself and from doing some research the best way is to do the workaround you suggested which would be to set the default value after it has initialised.

I found this answer from another user through a google search actually, haha: [How can I establish a default String value on a Tkinter Spinbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145376/how-can-i-establish-a-default-string-value-on-a-tkinter-spinbox)

This is intended behaviour actually due to how values is coded. The way values works is that it overrides other arguments in a sense, so it uses the first value you declare in values as the initial value and not your textvariable. I don't believe there is any way to fix this.

For reference: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/spinbox.htm#M22 then click on values and it will explain it.